# Which pattern will be best solution for creating instance of logged ApiClient, shared for all controllers

Tags: ios, swift, design-patterns, share

I use such mechanism of logging to server in my application: POST user credentials to server, which in case of success return to me token needed for signing my future API calls.
Question is how share this token (or instance of logged APIClient) between all classes of my application?

Now I make in every controller property "token" and when performing each segue I have to initialise it, which is too much boiler code, so I'm looking for solution share it other way. Thanks

Comment: You can create a class and a static variable and just call the class name and the variable

Comment: How I can create static variable with token, which will be known during runtime only?

Comment: What do you mean token? It's just a string that you have to pass in your api's call?

Comment: yes, but it depends on username/password pair, entered by user

Comment: Can you use the username/password as key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how to share this token (or instance of logged APIClient) between all classes of my application?

- Create a `shared instance` which is -

  - initialised on reception of success *token* from the network request
  - destroyed when the attributes(the success token) it is holding is not required anymore

Some sample code to achieve this:

```
// APIHelper.h

@interface APIHelper : NSObject

@property (nonatomic) NSString *mySuccessToken; // can be any data type

+ (instancetype)sharedInstance;

@end


// APIHelper.m

@implementation APIHelper

+ (instancetype)sharedInstance{
    static dispatch_once_t once;
    static APIHelper *sharedInstance;
    dispatch_once(&once, ^{
        sharedInstance = [self new];
    });
    return sharedInstance;
}

@end


// Usage of the APIHelper shared instance
// In the function responsible for firing the network request


[MyFetchRequestWithSuccess:^{
    ...

    [APIHelper sharedInstance].mySuccessToken = receivedSuccessToken; // update the shared instance with your received success token from the request       

} failure:^{ 
    ... 
}]
```